# How to remove an element from XML using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, parsing, nokogiri

Given this HTML:

```
 <products>
    <product>
      <name> product1 </name>
      <price> 21 </price>
    </product>
    <product>
      <name> product2 </name>
      <price> 0 </price>
    </product>
        <product>
      <name> product3 </name>
      <price> 10 </price>
    </product>
  </products>
```

I want to recreate an XML file using Nokogiri but I want to remove the elements where "products price = 0" so it looks like:

```
 <products>
    <product>
      <name> product1 </name>
      <price> 21 </price>
    </product>
    <product>
      <name> product3 </name>
      <price> 10 </price>
    </product>
  </products>
```

I tried lots of things but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We need to see what you tried, not just what you want to have happen. Beyond that, yes, Nokogiri's documentation is deep, because it's a complex and complicated tool. It requires time to understand how to use it but warrants the time spent to learn it because it can do a lot. But, "badly documented"? Nope. It's all there, but you're going to have to spend time learning it, like you would using Net::HTTP, any good SQL gem, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more idiomatic Nokogiri and Ruby code:

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml =<<EOT
 <products>
    <product>
      <name> product1 </name>
      <price> 21 </price>
    </product>
    <product>
      <name> product2 </name>
      <price> 0 </price>
    </product>
        <product>
      <name> product3 </name>
      <price> 10 </price>
    </product>
  </products>
EOT

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)

# strip the offending nodes
doc.xpath('//product/price[text()=" 0 "]/..').remove
```

At this point the resulting XML looks like:

```
doc.to_xml
# => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n" +
#    "<products>\n" +
#    "    <product>\n" +
#    "      <name> product1 </name>\n" +
#    "      <price> 21 </price>\n" +
#    "    </product>\n" +
#    "    \n" +
#    "        <product>\n" +
#    "      <name> product3 </name>\n" +
#    "      <price> 10 </price>\n" +
#    "    </product>\n" +
#    "  </products>\n"
```

Then simply `write` it:

```
File.write('myfile.xml', doc.to_xml)
```

Answer (score -1):

Nokogiri uses XPath and with that I could query the XML file:

It is as easy as this:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = File.open("file_with_your.xml") { |f| Nokogiri::XML(f) }   // load your file with xml content

c = doc.xpath("//product[price!=0]")                             //this is the query
puts c                                                           // you can print the results
File.open("myfile.xml", "w+") do |f|                             // and create another file
  f << c
end
```

Comment: Nokogiri allows you to use either XPath or CSS accessors. Which you chose to use is up to you; Each has its moment. But, really the documentation is very thorough and in depth, but it's a complex subject and has a definite learning curve, but that's not Nokogiri's fault, it's the result of working with HTML and XML which are not exactly simple subjects. SO is full of examples of how to read and write XML/HTML and parse and munge it using Nokogiri.

Comment: I'd recommend checking the output file. The output isn't going to be a valid XML.

Comment: Yes that is true. I had to add the header but it worked great.

Comment: Properly used, Nokogiri will retain the structure so you won't have to do that.